# Why does this ajax code generate "Cannot GET" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a script using ajax to send a POST request to the server. Server is written in flask. When I submit the form i get a browser page only with text:

> Cannot GET /login?email=my_email%40email.com&password=password&patient=n

Since it's saying cannot GET I'm assuming that it's the form submition that is causing the problem, not the actual sending to the server. I have also tested the back end (rest api) with a python test program and it works so I will not post that part. If you think it's meaningful to the resolution I can post it. Below is the script and the html form.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //set what happens when the "Enter" button is pressed
  $('form#login-form').submit(function(event) {
    login(event);
  });

  function login(event) {
    var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
    var password = $("input[name='password']").val();
    var patient = $("input[name='patient']:checked").val();
    var anorapp = '';
    var deviceid = '';

    if (userAgent.match(/Android/i))
      anorapp = 'android';
    else
      anorapp = 'ios';

    var json = {
      patient: patient,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      deviceid: deviceid,
      anorapp: anorapp
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/rest_api/v1.0/signin",
      data: JSON.stringify(json),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, status) {
        window.location.assign('map.html');
      },
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert('This account probably doesn\'t exist.');
        },
        403: function() {
          alert('You have may inserted the wrong password.');
        },
      }
    });
    //avoid form submission (the default action of the event)
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

HTML Form:

```html
<div class="w-form">
  <form id="login-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" data-redirect="map.html" action="/login">
    <div>
      <label class="label-form" for="email-field">E-MAIL</label>
      <input class="w-input input-form" id="email-field" type="email" name="email" data-name="email" required="required">
      <div class="separator-fields"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="label-form" for="email">PASSWORD</label>
      <div class="w-clearfix block-input-combined">
        <input class="w-input input-form left" id="password-field" type="password" name="password" data-name="password" required="required"><a class="right-input-link" href="forgot.html" data-load="1">Forgot Password</a>
      </div>
      <div class="separator-button-input"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="label-form middle" for="email">PATIENT?</label>
      <div class="w-clearfix input-form one-line">
        <div class="w-clearfix radios-container">
          <div class="w-radio w-clearfix radio-button">
            <div class="radio-bullet-replacement"></div>
            <input class="w-radio-input radio-bullet" id="patient-n" type="radio" name="patient" value="n" data-name="patient">
            <label class="w-form-label" for="patient-n">No</label>
          </div>
          <div class="w-radio w-clearfix radio-button">
            <div class="radio-bullet-replacement"></div>
            <input class="w-radio-input radio-bullet" id="patient-y" type="radio" name="patient" value="y" data-name="patient">
            <label class="w-form-label" for="patient-y">Yes</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="separator-fields"></div>
    </div>
    <input class="w-button action-button" type="submit" value="Sign In" data-wait="Please wait...">
    <div class="separator-button"></div><a class="link-upper" href="signup.html" data-load="1">YOU DON’T HAVE AN ACCOUNT? <strong class="b-link">SIGN UP</strong></a>
  </form>
  <div class="w-form-done">
    <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-form-fail">
    <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The script should work: [(slightly modified) fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tLmbbh3/). Check the console for any errors. Where is `userAgent` defined?

Comment: @Andreas Hi thank you. Adding navigator.userAgent removed the weird error. Now upon submition i get 200(success) in the console but it doesn't redirect to the map.html, do you maybe now why is that the case?

Comment: offtopic: you should never advise the user that an account doesn't exist vs the password is wrong.  If they get the 403, then hackers will know the account name is correct and can just blat that account with different passwords.

Comment: @freedomn-m I haven't personally developed this code. It is for a local university project where emphasis is on the "internet of things" concept. The server and the app/web page are purely for testing purposes, not for production. But irregardless, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The only important change in the fiddle is the `userAgent` part. If the fiddle works for you then you have to adopt the `window.naviagor.userAgent` part into the original script: `if (userAgent.match(/Android/i))` -> `if (window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))`

Comment: @Andreas I understood. windows.navigator.userAgent didn't work, but navigator.userAgent did. Now i am having a different issue where the redirect on succes is not working. Off topic: I would like to choose your comment as an answer since you did solve my original problem, but i can't seem to find the option. Maybe comments can't be chosen as answers.

Comment: Imho I think this question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. But feel free to answer your question yourself :)